# can we add Custom headers to Alamofire file download : IOS/SWIFT

Tags: ios, file, swift, download, alamofire

I know how to add custom headers to alamofire request, but is it possible to add custom headers to alamofire download ? Also, how to change the file extension that is being saved in the filepath ?

```
Alamofire.download(.GET, myURL, { (temporaryURL, response) in
      if let directoryURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        .URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory,
          inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
        as? NSURL {
          let pathComponent = response.suggestedFilename

          return directoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(pathComponent!)
      }
      return temporaryURL
    }).response{ (_,_, data, err) -> Void in
      println(data)
    }
```

Comment: You may get better results if you ask your two questions as separate questions.

Comment: as both are related to alamofire download i thought i can ask in them in one question. I will try creating another question after looking into the results. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Here's a code sample that matches yours using @mattt's suggestion of using an `NSURLRequest` with the header already attached.

```
let URLString = "whatever/floats/your/boat"
let URLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: URLString)!)
URLRequest.setValue("Header Value", forHTTPHeaderField: "Header Name")

let request = Alamofire.download(URLRequest) { temporaryURL, response in
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    if let directoryURL = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0] as? NSURL {
        let pathComponent = response.suggestedFilename
        return directoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(pathComponent!)
    }

    return temporaryURL
}

request.response { _, response, data, error in
    if let data = data as? NSData {
        println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
    } else {
        println(response)
        println(error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution for this.

```
var headers = Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders ?? [:]
    headers = [ "X-ApiKey" : "someValue",
      "Content-Type" : "application/json; charset=utf-8"]

    let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = headers

    let manager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: configuration)
    let destination = Alamofire.Request.suggestedDownloadDestination(directory: .DocumentDirectory, domain: .UserDomainMask)
    manager.download(.GET, "place your URL here", destination: destination)
      .progress { (bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead) in
        println(totalBytesRead)
      }
      .response { (request, response, data, error) in
        fileName = response?.suggestedFilename
        completionHandler(fileName: fileName as String?, error: error)
        println(data)
    }
```

hope this helps someone. Thank you

Comment: A much simpler approach would be to call `download` passing an `NSURLRequest` object with the desired headers.

Comment: The second line in your code, shouldn't it be
headers["X-ApiKey"] = "some value";
or
headers += ["X-ApiKey": "some value"]